# Python OpenCV Stitcher Class documentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

Could you please give me some hint where can I find a detailed documentation for the Python Stitcher Class?

I was able to find examples, and implemented them but I'd like to know more about this class and its capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python support from OpenCV is basically a set of bindings for the lower level C++ functions, so you can have a look at the C++ documentation for it:

https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html

, with some C++ examples quoted in the docs.

A more general overview of the stitching in OpenCV can be found at:

https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d46/group__stitching.html

It might also help to have a look at the backend code for the stitcher:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp

I know all the above is C++, but OpenCV is mainly a C++ library with Python bindings. Just having a look around can help tremendously.